# Robotframework - Pycharm is not showing suggestions

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework, intellibot

[image: No Suggestions]

[image: Python Interpreter]

[image: Plugins installed]

I have made all the configurations but Pycharm is not giving any suggestions. please help

Comment: Did you try restarting PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution is to reset the settings to default.

"From the main menu, select File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings.Alternatively, press Shift twice and type Restore default settings."